# How to scrape and construct price that is in the same div but different sub classes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to construct a price out of two different tags (see picture bellow). How do you nest the search so it looks in the div class="price", for span, and sub tags?

[image]

How do I get out the numbers from span and sub tags in div class="price"

I have tried the following:

```
coldbeetrootsoup=BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')

try:
    price = coldbeetrootsoup.find("span",{"class": None}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    price = None

try:
    subprice = coldbeetrootsoup.find("sub",{"class": None}).text.replace('\n',"")
except:
    subprice = None
```

link: https://www.rimi.lt/e-parduotuve/lt/produktai/vaisiai-darzoves-ir-geles/vaisiai-ir-uogos/obuoliai-/fas-liet-obuoliai-ligol-nuraude-anyks-vnt/p/923923

target: price 1.39 EUR

Comment: Can you share a link (or full html text)?

Comment: I have edited to add a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want is

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get(
    "https://www.rimi.lt/e-parduotuve/lt/produktai/vaisiai-darzoves-ir-geles/vaisiai-ir-uogos/obuoliai-/fas-liet-obuoliai-ligol-nuraude-anyks-vnt/p/923923").text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

price_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "price"})
full_part = price_div.find("span").text
cents_part = price_div.find("sup").text
currency = price_div.find("sub").text

currency = re.sub("\s+", "", currency)

print(f"{full_part}.{cents_part} {currency}")  # 1.39 €/vnt.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by defining the div you want to dig into, in this case it is the div with the class 'price', you do this just like you already are trying to do with the spans:

```
price = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'price'})
```

once we have this price, we can instead of searching the whole html, just search for the wanted tags within this div, as such:

```
euro = price.find('span')
cent = price.find('sup')
```

now to get what you want, you can do:

```
print(f"{euro.text}.{cent.text}")
```

or if you want the float variable

```
price_tag = round((int(euro.text) + (int(cent.text)/100)),2)
```

Here we divide the cent with 100 or else it wouldn't be in cents, and we use the round tag to only get two decimal points.